# Layout attributes not working in Polymer Dart

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I'm trying to play around with core-elements and paper-elements in Dart Polymer, and in doing so trying to style them using the layout attributes documented at http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html.  When I run my project though, it seems that none of the layout attributes are actually being processed.  The link says that

> "The layout attributes are implemented in layout.html - a file included whenever you import Polymer in your element."

Which seems to imply that it's all pretty automatic.  So far I've been able to get `fit` and `flex` working, as well as the numbered ratios, but it seems like everything else, such as changing colors or justification, is having no effect, even with html copied straight from the examples on the polymer site.  Am I missing something special I need to do, or does Dart's version of Polymer not support most of these layout attributes?  If it's a lack of current support, where can I look to see what is and isn't currently supported in Dart Polymer?

Comment: Can you add some concrete code example of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using the layout examples from [this page](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html) quite extensively with good success.

An simple example of centering my login box on the login page is below:

```
<body fullbleed layout horizontal center-justified unresolved>   
  <div layout vertical center-justified>
    <phx-login></phx-login>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Fwiw, you can probably simplify to `<body fullbleed layout horizontal center-center unresolved><phx-login></phx-login></body>`